# changing multiple state value - react

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a state object that represents rows and columns that looks something like this.

```
  const [state, setState] = useState([
    { firstName: "example", lastName: "example", petName: "example" },
    { firstName: "example", lastName: "example", petName: "example" },
    { firstName: "example", lastName: "example", petName: "example" },
  ]);
```

how can I set my state to change the key of all the petName values whilst keeping the original state?

Comment: Why did you delete your new question, I wrote the answer for you - updating the value of state object in react.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `spread operator`:

```js
const [state, setState] = useState([
    { firstName: "example", lastName: "example", petName: "example" },
    { firstName: "example", lastName: "example", petName: "example" },
    { firstName: "example", lastName: "example", petName: "example" },
  ]);

{...}

const changePetNames = (newValue) => setState(state => state.map(obj => {...obj, petName: newValue}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to change all the values as it's an array:

```js
console.log([{
    firstName: "example1",
    lastName: "example1",
    petName: "example"
  },
  {
    firstName: "example2",
    lastName: "example2",
    petName: "example"
  },
  {
    firstName: "example3",
    lastName: "example3",
    petName: "example"
  },
].map((p, i) => ({
  ...p,
  petName: "New Name " + (i + 1)
})));
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's a simple way to do it. This will keep the value of the key just update the name.

```
setState((prevState) =>
      prevState.map((state) => {
        state["newKey"] = state.petName;
        delete state["petName"];
      })
    );
```